# How to remove multiple HTML tags containing certain text strings from a Wordpress posts using the DOMDocument with get_the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, domdocument

Ok, so what I have is a wordpress site with a lot of posts containing many paragraphs I don't need. Using a SQL query to remove these from the database would be ideal, however I doubt it can be done, so I'm focusing on getting the post content with the get_the_content() and filtering what I don't need using the DOMDocument. To make things more complicated, these elements cannot be identified by ids or classes.

**Example**: I have a WP article/post containing this sentence:

```
<p>How is everything going today?</p>
```

I want to search for "How is" (case insensitive, if possible) and remove the entire P element.

This is what I have got so far:

```
    <?php
    // the_content();
    error_reporting(0);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(strip_tags(mb_convert_encoding(get_the_content(), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), '<a>,<iframe>,<figure>,<figcaption>,<video>,<img>,<p>,<br>,<div>,<table>,<thead>,<tbody>,<tfoot>,<tr>,<th>,<td>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_NOERROR);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    //this should keep the BR tags 
    foreach ($xpath->query('//br') as $br) {
      $br->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode("\n"), $br);
    }
    //this should remove empty html tags
    while (($node_list = $xpath->query('//*[not(*) and not(@*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]')) && $node_list->length) {
        foreach ($node_list as $node) {
         $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
    }
//this should remove the &nbsp; only tags
    $nbsp = $xpath->query("//*[text()=\" \xC2\xA0\" or text()=\"\xC2\xA0\"]"); # this should remove &nbsp; ony elements such as <p>&nbsp;</p> or <p> &nbsp;</p> 
    foreach($nbsp as $e) {
        $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
    }
    //this should remove tags containing certain text strings - THIS IS THE ISSUE
    foreach ($xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(.,'This is a') //I want this to remove <p>This is a sentence I do not want.</p>
    or contains(.,'This is another') //I want this to remove <span>This is another sentence I do not want.</span>
    or contains(.,'height:') //I want this to remove <span>height:50px;width:40px</span>
    or contains(.,'înapoi') //I want this to remove <i>Înainte, nu inapoi</i>
    ]]") as $attr) {
         $attr->parentNode->removeChild($attr);
    }
    echo wpautop($dom->saveHTML(), true);
    ?>
```

This is working, but not always, and I cannot understand why. Sometimes all the text from the post is removed. Other times, even if the sentence is in a **p** paragraph at the end of the post, it gets removed along with other 2-3 paragraphs before it. It seems to happen random, for some posts it is working, for others not.

I should mention that there are almost 150 sentences/strings that I need removed, so I have almost 150 *or contains* lines. Maybe too many and the site cannot handle them?!

So, is there anything with my code, or do you have other better idea about how to remove elements (p, div, span, any basically) containing certain text strings?

If it matters, I'm on an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, running Wordpress on nginx and php 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I will try again to give a more precise answer.
You want to

1. keep the br tags
2. remove empty tags
3. remove `&nbsp;`-tags
4. replace some strings

point 3.) There are no  -tags. This you can only see in the Wordpress-Editor, but not in the frontend. In the database I think there is always a line break between two paragraphs then `&nbsp;`. (a space) and again a line break. Wordpress then makes P-tags out of this in the output. However, this can also be turned off completely. (End of code.)

1.,2.,4.)

functions.php

```php
    // 1. br tags will stay
    // 3. replace strings
    function replaceTextinTheContent($the_content){
        $replace = array(
            // 'WORD TO REPLACE' => 'REPLACE WORD WITH THIS'
            '<span>This is another sentence I do not want.</span>' => '',
            '<i>Înainte, nu inapoi</i>'             => 'bar',
            '<span>height:50px;width:40px</span>'   => '',
            'This is a sentence I do not want.'     => '', // P-tags are not saved in the Database, so we could only search the text
        );
        $the_content = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $the_content);
        return $the_content;
    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'replaceTextinTheContent',998); //998, to execute the script as second to last


    // 2. remove empty tags
    function removeEmptyParagraphs($content) {
    
        //$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; // use this pattern to only delete P-tags
        $pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/"
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);

        return $content;
    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'removeEmptyParagraphs', 999); //999, to execute the script as last

    // bonus: don't load P-tags
    function disableWpAutoP( $content ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
        return $content;
    }
    
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'disableWpAutoP', 0 );
```

i've not testet this. but i think it should work. :D

screenshot of the post_content in wp_posts table:
[image: screenshot of the post_content in wp_posts table]

---

OLD:
i think you should try this in your functions.php

I don't get the point of your method.. maybe i'm missing whats your goal.

```php
function replaceTextinTheContent($the_content){
    $replace = array(
        // 'WORD TO REPLACE' => 'REPLACE WORD WITH THIS'
        'foo' => 'bar',
    );
    $the_content = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $the_content);
    return $the_content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replaceTextinTheContent',99);
```

Comment: Sorry, my explanation must be confusing. The point is to replace all the elements (such as div, p, span and so on) containing any of the text strings, even though they might contain other text as well. Str_replace, as far as I know, replaces only the string, it doesn't have the possibility to replace the element containing that string. Hence, the phpdom I'm trying to perfect.

Comment: I've edited the post and the code with hopefully better explanations

Comment: Hey, i think the problem is that there are no p-tags in the Wordpress Database. Take a look in "post_content" of "wp_posts" table. Only the headline markup is in that field. the p-tags are added from wordpress when printing the content.

So when you use my code and simply change 
'foo' => 'bar' 
to 
'How is everything going today?' => ''

This should remove the entire p-tags.

Comment: Better would be to search and replace the strings in the database. I would recommend this tool: https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
But first you should check how exaclty the parts look in the database. With this tool you can replace everything including the tags and it keeps the database serialization correct.

Comment: @GadgetsMall I update my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but you still didn't understand. What I need is only the part of 'THIS IS THE ISSUE' from my code = to remove any html tag (p,div,span,customname) if it contains a certain text string. I cannot explain it any better than this. Thanks for your help.